# Read More” and readless not working in labelrenderer ios xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, uilabel, multiline

[image]

I have Labelrenderer initially it shows single line once i tab readmore, It cannot expanded show single line only in ios. how to achieve this using renderer below screenshot

### Xaml

```
<Label Text="{Binding Comment}" LineBreakMode="{Binding CommentBrkMode}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start">
                                                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.ShowMoreCommand,Source={x:Reference Page}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                            </Label>

<Label Text="{Binding CommentViewText}" IsVisible="{Binding ReadMoreLabelVisible}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" TextColor="Blue" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                                                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.ShowMoreCommand,Source={x:Reference Page}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                            </Label>
public class CustomLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
{
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                if (Element.LineBreakMode == LineBreakMode.TailTruncation)
                {
                    Control.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false; //for purists
                    Control.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.TailTruncation; //the fix
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Which library are you using for the label in forms ? Could you provide it so that we can  test ?

Comment: We can't use any particular library use in labelrenderer

Comment: Could you please show the code in xaml ?

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT added above xaml

Comment: Are you using `TTTAttributedLabel` to implement the readmore function ? If so could you provide the complete code ?

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT  No that is reference am not using TTTAttributedlabel,  i want show like above screenshot but in our project if i tab readmore it cannot expand android works well ios only not working

Comment: Actually I use the same code you provided there is no `ReadMore` at the tail , it's just showing the three dots.

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT above xaml label added we are using both, i dont know how it work on android, i think issue in ios renderer

Comment: Could you provide a basic, reproducible project to us ? You can upload to github and attach the link here .

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT as per company policy we are not attaching our project but am sure to tell u issue in renderer only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236387/discussion-between-colex-msft-and-newxamarin).